# How to use TableClientOptions with TableClient for Azure Table Storage retries?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm using the `TableClient` to connect to an Azure Table Storage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet

I need to implement a retry mechanism. I could just do a custom implementation but I noticed there is this `TableClientOptions` which I can pass in the constructor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet

which has a `Retry` property of type `RetryOptions`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet

So I assumed to use this I would do like this:

```
TableClientOptions opts = new TableClientOptions(TableClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_02_02);
opts.Retry = new RetryOptions
{
    Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    Mode = RetryMode.Fixed,
    MaxRetries = 5
};

TableClient tablClient = new TableClient(connStr, tblName, opts);
```

My issue is that line 3 fails because there is no public constructor on RetryOptions. The constructors it provides are internal so I can't even just create an inheriting class.

There is also a public static `Default` instance on the `ClientOptions` type so I tried setting the values in there but that didn't bare any results either.

So my question is: how do I use these options to make use of the suggested retry mechanism?

Comment: Hi Daniel, feel free to [accept any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was of any help to you. If it isn't, feel free to ask for details.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the `Retry` properties instead of creating a new instance of `RetryOptions`:

```cs
    TableClientOptions opts = new TableClientOptions(TableClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_02_02);
    opts.Retry.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    opts.Retry.Mode = RetryMode.Fixed;
    opts.Retry.MaxRetries = 5;
```